# HTML link to page of other server on same LAN

Tags: html, hyperlink, server, ip, lan

I host my own website from home on an Ubuntu Apache server, and port-forward to it from my router for HTTP: and HTTPS: - it works well.

I'd like to remotely access the web interface of my NAS which sits on my home LAN, and have tried building a simple page on my site to link to the NAS web interface, but am clutching at straws.

To locally view the NAS web interface, this works in a browser bar: http://192.168.1.75/

I've had a stab at linking to this from an html file of my website:

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.75/">NAS 1</a>
```

Clearly this won't work, can anyone please help me to build a link that will work?

The test page is at [www.scottbouch.com/a.html](https://www.scottbouch.com/a.html)

Many thanks, Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access it remotely (other location over the internet) you need to use you outbound IP (here you can find it http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

If it is for local use only, make sure you have the right port: 80 / 8080 or for https 443 etc and they are open.

Comment: My ISP changes my Routers external IP regularly, but my domain name www.scottbouch.com always points to my server as I use a DDNS service. Browsing to the LAN IP of my NAS locally works, but I want to be able to see it while I'm away from home, utilising my domain name.